# Gaining access to association owner object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm looking to gain access to the owner of the `elements` association in the following code inside the `Processor` module. First up, `Chapter.process` is called:

**app/models/chapter.rb**

```
class Chapter
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :position, :type => Integer
  field :title, :type => String
  field :identifier, :type => String

  embedded_in :book
  embeds_many :elements

  def self.process!(git, file)
    chapter = new
    # Parsing of XML goes here, generating parsed_doc
    elements = parsed_doc.css("div.chapter > *")
    elements.each { |element| chapter.elements.process!(element) }
  end
```

This then passes off to the code inside `Processor`, which is actually included into the `Element` class like this:

**app/models/element.rb**

```
class Element
  include Mongoid::Document
  extend Processor
  field :tag, :type => String
  field :identifier, :type => String
  field :title, :type => String

  embedded_in :chapter
end
```

Where the `Processor` class is defined like this:

```
module Processor

  def process!(markup)
    [ASSOCIATION OWNER GOES HERE].elements.send("process_#{markup.name}!", markup)
  end
```

The reason I need this is because I have attempted to simply call `send` by itself but Monogid insists that:

> Access to the collection for Element is not allowed since it is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root document.

And so it would seem the only way to do this would be to access the parent object for this association. I know that there's supposed to be a `_parent` method on instances of document, but in this case this method is being called on the *collection*, not an instance.

So how can I reference the association object from within this `process!` method?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, but what if you will pass it straight `chapter.elements.process!(element, chapter)` from `Chapter`?

Comment: @fl00r: I would rather not do that, given that the `create!` method in Element must somehow know what Chapter it is being created for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here is that you are extending the module, so the `self` will reference class instead of the element instance. If you change the module to be included in Element or by any other means make the method `process!` an instance method, you can do `self.chapter.elements`.

In case element can be embedded in other models than chapter `self._parent.elements` would be a better choice, but I would not recommend it as it is not documented and might change in future versions of mongoid without notice.

Comment: Thanks, I worked around this by using fl00r's suggestion. Your's is the closest.

Answer (score 1):

With Mongoid you cannot do this the way you are proposing until after creation of the parent object, as chapter is not yet persisted when you call self.process!, you have no "root document". The only way to get this to work given your constraints will be to call self.process! from an after_create filter once the chapter object has been created.